# How to write multiple css selectors in one line?

Tags: css, css-selectors

My problem is that i want to write this in single selection :

```
.btn-primary > i.glyphicon {
    color: #ffffff;
}
.btn-primary > span.glyphicon {
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

But this :

```
.btn-primary > i.glyphicon, span.glyphicon {
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

doesnt work. Because all the span.glyphicon tags are geting white color. How do solve this?

Comment: In [selectors level 4](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors-4/), there's a pseudo class called [`:matches()`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors-4/#matches) which can be used to select a comma separated selector list: `.btn-primary > :matches(i.glyphicon, span.glyphicon)`. But as of writing it is not supported by common web browsers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Comma separate them:

```
.btn-primary > i.glyphicon,
.btn-primary > span.glyphicon {
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

More info can be found at [w3.org about grouping](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#grouping).

If you want to 'shortcut' them, you'll need a CSS pre-processor, like SCSS or SASS.

Comment: @JoshCrozier: thanks for the fill-up, I've added it to the answer.