# Single CSS select statement for all td and th elements inside a certain class

Tags: css, html-table, css-selectors

This should be pretty simple but the answer is eluding me. What I have works but it consists of two select statements instead of 1. I want to select all `th` and `td` elements inside an element with class `.table-std`.

What I have results in the table with class table-std having correct borders (around table and around each cell, with borders collapsed). Other, tables that are not of this class are unaffected.

```css
.table-std th {
    border: 1px solid var(--border-color);
    padding: 0.25em;
}

.table-std td {
    border: 1px solid var(--border-color);
    padding: 0.25em;
}
```

This selects all td in .table-std

```css
.table-std th td {
    border: 1px solid var(--border-color);
    padding: 0.25em;
}
```

This seems to selects all td in .table-std

```css
.table-std th td {
    border: 1px solid var(--border-color);
    padding: 0.25em;
}
```

This seems to selects all th and td in .table-std, but at least all td in other tables too.

```css
.table-std th, td{
    border: 1px solid var(--border-color);
    padding: 0.25em;
}
```

Same with this.

```css
.table-std, th, td{
    border: 1px solid var(--border-color);
    padding: 0.25em;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29685752/how-to-write-multiple-css-selectors-in-one-line/29685762 -- see this.

Comment: I was thinking maybe there was another way of specifying the relationship between the classes/elements that I was missing. Nevertheless, yes, that addresses my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this selector:

```
.table-std th,
.table-std td {
    border: 1px solid var(--border-color);
    padding: 0.25em;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the class .table-std is only associated with the **th & td** you wish to edit.

And the use the second to the last code in your question